# Merge query returning ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: sql, .net, oracle

I have two merge queries which triggers one after another

**First Query**

```
merge into MyTable
using
(   
select distinct nullLogSetId.Id as IdToUpdate,
       knownLogSetId.LogSetId LogSetIdToUpdateTo
from MyTable knownLogSetId 
join MyTable nullLogSetId
  on knownLogSetId.IdentifierType = nullLogSetId.IdentifierType
 and knownLogSetId.Identifier = nullLogSetId.Identifier 
where 

    knownLogSetId.IdentifierType = 'ABC'
    and knownLogSetId.LogSetId >= 0 
    and nullLogSetId.LogSetId = -1
)
on (Id = IdToUpdate)
when matched then
update set LogSetId = LogSetIdToUpdateTo
```

**Second Query**

```
merge into MyTable
using
(

  select distinct nullLogSetId.Id as IdToUpdate,
                  knownLogSetId.LogSetId LogSetIdToUpdateTo
  from MyTable knownLogSetId 
  join MyTable nullLogSetId
    on knownLogSetId.IdentifierType = nullLogSetId.IdentifierType 
   and knownLogSetId.Identifier = nullLogSetId.Identifier 
  where 
    knownLogSetId.IdentifierType = 'DEF'
    and knownLogSetId.LogSetId >= 0 
    and nullLogSetId.LogSetId = -1
) on (Id = IdToUpdate)
when matched then
update set LogSetId = LogSetIdToUpdateTo
```

I am calling these queries from .NET one after another using OracleCommand

The first works fine but when second gets triggered i am getting error

> **ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables**

I have read all the relevent questions and tried from my side as well , if you see i used distinct in both of the queries so duplicating of rows is not an issue.
Can please anybody help me out what i am i doing wrong , it could be a basic stuff as i am new to queries , please help me out

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> if you see i used distinct in both of the queries so duplicating of
>   rows is not an issue.

You probably have duplicates in data. **`DISTINCT` does not guarantee you have `IdToUpdate` unique when you use it with other columns.** See:

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable(IdToUpdate INT, LogSetIdToUpdateTo INT);

INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (2,1),(3,1);

SELECT DISTINCT IdToUpdate, LogSetIdToUpdateTo
FROM #MyTable;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/387950)**</kbd>

You will get `IdToUpdate` twice. Check your data:

```
with cte AS (
  select distinct nullLogSetId.Id as IdToUpdate,
                  knownLogSetId.LogSetId LogSetIdToUpdateTo
  from MyTable knownLogSetId 
  join MyTable nullLogSetId
    on knownLogSetId.IdentifierType = nullLogSetId.IdentifierType 
   and knownLogSetId.Identifier = nullLogSetId.Identifier 
  where 
    knownLogSetId.IdentifierType = 'DEF'
    and knownLogSetId.LogSetId >= 0 
    and nullLogSetId.LogSetId = -1
)
SELECT IdToUpdate, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM cte
GROUP BY IdToUpdate
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

One way to go is to use aggregation function`(MAX/MIN)` instead of `DISTINCT`:

```
merge into MyTable
using
(

  select nullLogSetId.Id as IdToUpdate,
         MAX(knownLogSetId.LogSetId) AS LogSetIdToUpdateTo 
  from MyTable knownLogSetId 
  join MyTable nullLogSetId
    on knownLogSetId.IdentifierType = nullLogSetId.IdentifierType 
   and knownLogSetId.Identifier = nullLogSetId.Identifier 
  where 
    knownLogSetId.IdentifierType = 'DEF'
    and knownLogSetId.LogSetId >= 0 
    and nullLogSetId.LogSetId = -1
  GROUP BY nullLogSetId.Id
) on (Id = IdToUpdate)
when matched then
update set LogSetId = LogSetIdToUpdateTo
```

Comment: Thanks alot @lad2025 the distinct cause me overconfident your answer was perfect.

Comment: @Anamay You're welcome. One lesson in SQL world is to `never take anything for granted. Check it first.` :)