# Oracle merge into statements not working properly

Tags: oracle, merge

I am running the following two merge into queries in oracle and the first one is running but the second merge into statement in not running. It returns the following response: ORA-30926:unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables.

Both the queries are using the same tables and are quite similar. The only difference between them is that the second merge query is using three 'ON' conditions while the first uses only two 'ON' conditions.

I need to get a workaround so that my intention with the second query gets fulfilled. Please help.

Query 1)

```
MERGE INTO loc_final_2_exp t USING (        
    SELECT DISTINCT upper(trim(city)) as city, 
                    upper(trim(state)) as state, 
                    upper(trim(county)) as county  
    FROM audtr_rgn_assgnmnts) a     
    ON (upper(trim(t.city)) = a.city AND 
        upper(trim(t.state)) = a.state)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.county = a.county;
```

Query2)

```
MERGE INTO loc_final_2_exp t USING (     
    SELECT DISTINCT  upper(trim(city)) as city, 
                     upper(trim(state)) as state, 
                     upper(trim(county)) as county, 
                     upper(trim(auditor)) as auditor
    FROM audtr_rgn_assgnmnts) a   
    ON (upper(trim(t.county))=a.county and 
        upper(trim(t.city)) = a.city and 
        upper(trim(t.state)) = a.state)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.loc_status = a.auditor;
```

Comment: refer this link since your inner query imay be giving duplicates ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627802/merge-query-returning-ora-30926-unable-to-get-a-stable-set-of-rows-in-the-sourc?rq=1

Comment: Apparently there is more than one row for at least one combination of (city, state, county) in the `AUDTR_RGN_ASSGNMNTS` table, with different values for `AUDITOR`. In that case, which `AUDITOR` value should be used for the update? Either you have errors in the data, and the `AUDITOR` **should** be completely determined by (city, state, county) (in which case you must fix the data first - find the errors and correct them), or else the problem itself makes no sense, regardless of any code (or even, regardless of computers and databases in general).

Answer (score 1):

The information you've given for your case is insufficient, i.e you have not explained what is your DB structure, with focus on what are the primary keys and unique keys/constraints in those two tables. You have not shown the sample data.

As the documentation describes, the "ORA-30926:unable to get a stable set of rows..." error means, that your merge statement matching criteria cause more than one row of the merge source match at least one row in the target table.

And no, it's not just the list of conditions that is different between your two statements. You also have a different set of columns returned by the second sub-query, which - with `DISTINCT` in place - would suggest, that you have entries with different `auditor` values for some combinations of `city`, `state` and `country` in the `audtr_rgn_assgnmnts` table.